# Error 11007: Entity type 'tableName' is not mapped. Is it because the primary key of tha table is a identity column?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4 to generate my entities from the database. I get the following error while I am trying to compile my `Model` assembly (the edmx file in a separate assembly). I get the error only on tables, who have there primary keys as identity columns. Is that an issue? or am I just making wrong judgements?

```
Error 11007: Entity type 'tableName' is not mapped.
```

Steps

1. Using `Entity data model wizard` I created my `Model` (edmx file).
2. Right click the edmx file and `Add Code Generation Item` to create the entities (using  `Ado.net self tracking entity generator`).
3. Move the entities to a different assembly by moving the `x.tt` and edit it to point to the edmx file in a different assembly.
4. Now the entity and model (edmx) are in different assembles, to enabled me to have a multi tier application.

I am unable to build the `Model` assembly and I get the error

```
Error 11007: Entity type 'tableName' is not mapped.
```

I have checked for solutions online. Yes, all my tables have a primary key and association between them is defined with terms of foreign keys. Any pointers on this?

Thanks,
Dolly

Comment: Your question has been asked after your post, but has been answered. It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859196/entity-framework-error-11007-entity-type-is-not-mapped