# Entity Framework - Error 11007: Entity type is not mapped.

Tags: entity-framework

I have a problem when I got the lasted .edmx.

I get a message that says
Error 11007: Entity type 'pl_Micro' s not mapped.
Looking at the designer view, I do see that this table does indeed exist.

How can I overcome this meesage?

Comment: Just double click on the error. It will select the entity and hit delete. Update the model again and see if the entity is well part of the model

Comment: Willem's suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From MSDN:

> Error 11007: Entity Type Is Not Mapped

This error occurs when an entity type in the conceptual model is not mapped to the data source. To resolve this error, map the entity type to the data source. Look at the MSDN link

[How to: Map Entities to Database Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738478%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

Comment: A quicker way for me was to delete the tables and re-add them. Auto-mapped them. :)

Comment: If you remove the table from the Model Browser Store and not the Entity Types as well, that error will come up

Comment: I had a problem with step 3 in the 'Mapping Entities' article, in that there weren't any tables to choose from in the drop-down.  To solve that, right-click the .edmx in the model browser and choose "update model from database".  Choose tables you want to map to.  They'll be added to the model and you may not want that (wrong names in my case), but then you can map preexisting ones then remove the new ones if you need.

Answer (score 5):

I get this error when I move a database table to a different schema or delete a database table.  In this case Entity Framework doesn't seem to update the edmx file correctly when you *Update Model from Database...*.

The way I resolved this was to do a text search for the name of the offending entity.  I then removed all references to this in the xml view of the edmx file, deleted the corresponding cs file that defines the entity, and any other references in the project.

Answer (score 2):

This error was passed to me by the SQL Server Authentication server did not have the necessary permissions and could not see the entities.

Confirm that your sql user has the necessary permissions in the database.

Answer (score 2):

This happens also when you import tables via diagram in edmx and then you point in app.config to different instance of database (switching from dev db to test db for example)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because I had copy pasted an entity and modified it. Restarting visual studio resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, close visual study, enter the * .edmx file with a notepad ++, sublime text, notepad, etc., search the table, search the column and modify the column size (MaxLength), in all matches, in My case was 2, but they can be more. Start visual studio and the change is already accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I had to update the table column type.
Refresh table in SQL server and re-add table in the entity framework for resolving this.